# Socket.io api inconsistency or how does it work?

Tags: socket.io

When I do:

```
socket.join('room');
socket.to('room').emit('online');
```

the 'online'-event is never received on the client side.

When I do:

```
 socket.join('room');
 io.to('room').emit('online');
```

the 'online'-event is received on the client side.

When I do:

```
socket.join('room', () => {
    socket.to('room').emit('online');
});
```

the 'online'-event is never received on the client side.

The docs state the following:

http://socket.io/docs/server-api/#socket#to(room:string):socket

If I read this the call to:

```
socket.to('room').emit('online');
```

should be emitted to the room.

If I use the call:

```
socket.broadcast.to('room').emit('online');
```

the event should emit to the room except the socket.

Now it looks like that:

```
socket.to('room').emit('online');
```

and

```
io.to('room').emit('online');
```

are different. But what I read from the docs I read that they are the same.

Can someone explain the differences and why behave different?

Comment: Well, the real answer here is that socket.io is a well written library with very poor and incomplete documentation.  Lots of things are not documented and the documentation that does exist is very shallow and often leaves out things you need or want to know.  The only way I've found to get real answers to questions like this is to set up a test scenario and step through the code in the debugger to see what the actual socket.io code does and how it behaves.

Comment: Because it is so mature, it's pretty annoying that the docs state that socket.to('room') should work, but this isn't the case. It only works together with the broadcast flag.